# Argparse: nested optional argument, force --arg=val over --arg val, single occurrence, optional argument order

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

The program should be executed as follows:

```
./interpret.py --help | --source=FILE1 [--stats=FILE2 [--vars] [--insts]]
```

the rules are:

1. --help has to be the only argument if passed
2. --source=FILE1 has to be provided and can't be passed like --source FILE1
3. if --vars or --insts is provided, then --stats=FILE2 has to be provided
4. the order of --vars and --insts matters, therefore has to be stored
5. multiple occurrence of an argument is forbidden

I have read multiple tutorials and SO answers, but they don't even remotly cover my problem. Managed to do the following:

```
# parses command line arguments
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument('--source')
    parser.add_argument('--stats')
    parser.add_argument('--vars', action='count', default=0)
    parser.add_argument('--insts', action='count', default=0)
    parser.add_argument('--help', action='count', default=0)

    try:
        args = parser.parse_args()
    catch SystemExit:
        exit(ERR_PARAM)

    if args.help > 0:
        if args.source != None or args.stats != None or (args.help + args.vars + args.insts) != 1:
            exit(ERR_PARAM)

        manual()
        exit(0)

    if args.source == None:
        exit(ERR_PARAM)

    if args.vars > 1 or args.insts > 1:
        exit(ERR_PARAM)

    if (args.vars + args.insts) > 0 and args.stats == None:
        exit(ERR_PARAM)

    return args
```

The code has the following problems:

1. --source and --stats can be passed multiple times
2. --source and --stats can be passed like --source FILE1
3. the order of --vars --insts is not stored anywhere

Comment: Why *1) --help has to be the only argument if passed*? That's not how the majority of command-line interfaces work. Users start with a command line, get stuck after the two options they do remember, so they want to add `-h` / `--help` at the end to look at the help, and then use the shell history to return to the command, remove `-h` and add the switch they just read about in the help. If you *require* that the help switch is the only one, you go counter to this.

Comment: *2) --source=FILE1 has to be provided and can't be passed like --source FILE1*. You can't make argparse behave like this. It'll always accept either.

Comment: None of your requirements can be met with argparse. You'll have to code your own command-line argument parser. Perhaps `getopt` can help there.

Comment: *the order of --vars --insts is not stored anywhere*: it is, in `sys.argv`. Why must they be given in that order, what problem is created when they are given in a different order?

Comment: *1) --source and --stats can be passed multiple times*: you can create a custom action that throws an error if the attribute is already set on the namespace.

Comment: Given these requirements it will simpler to parse sys.argv directly.

Comment: Does enforcing these rules help you understand what the user wants? Or help the user provide the desired information in a clear and unambiguous fashion?  For example, if they want `help`, should it matter where they put the `-h`?