# How to prevent multiple occurrence of an optional argument with choices

Tags: python, argparse

I am using argparse in python 2.7. I'd like to prevent the user from calling my_app.py with multiple 
--cache optional argument. -cache (or --cache) is optional argument with choices and have a const and a default values. the code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-cache","-- 
cache",required=False,const='all',default=None,nargs='?',choices=["server-only","local-only","all"], 
help="Activate Cache by choosing one of the list choices. e.g. -cache=local-only")
```

I want to raise an exception when user calls my_app.py in the form below:

```
#if he calls with multiple --cache arguments, argparse takes the last dilvered one !! But i want to 
raise an exception here!
my_app.py --cache --cache=server-only
```

No suffcient answer was fond in this similar Q. in the link [multiple argument occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506868/argparse-nested-optional-argument-force-arg-val-over-arg-val-single-occur)

Comment: One solution would be to save the option values in a list.  Then, after options have been parsed, check the list length and give an error is it's 2 or more.  Use `action="append"` with `default=[]` to collect the option values in a list.

Comment: @TomKarzes - great and fast answer. Before i post my question i have tried to go on this concept exactly (the same thoughts ), and i have changed default to hold a list but the only thing i missed behind is the action="apend"! Thanks.

Comment: The default `argparse` behavior is to put the `default` in the namespace, and then allow each instance to over write it, in effect ending up with the last user provided value (if any).  Why fight that?  Are your users especially like to use `--cache --cache=foobar` with some special intent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a custom action that "remembers" the first time the option is used, then raises an exception if it is used a second time.

```
import argparse


class OneTimeAction(argparse._StoreAction):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OneTimeAction, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.seen = False

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.seen:
            parser = args[0]
            option_string = args[3]
            parser.error("Cannot use {} a second time".format(option_string))
        super(OneTimeAction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.seen = True


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-cache", "--cache", 
                    action=OneTimeAction,
                    default="all",
                    choices=["server-only", "local-only", "all"],
                    help="Activate Cache by choosing one of the list choices. e.g. -cache=local-only")
```

More generally, you can define this as a mix-in to be used with any kind of action. The following example also folds much of the configuration of the argument into the custom action itself.

```
import argparse


class OneTimeMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OneTimeMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.seen = False

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.seen:
            parser = args[0]
            option_string = args[3]
            parser.error("Cannot use {} a second time".format(option_string))
        super(OneTimeMixin, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.seen = True


class CacheAction(OneTimeMixin, argparse._StoreAction):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # setdefault ensures you can override these if desired
        kwargs.setdefault('choices', ["server-only", "local-only", "all"])
        kwargs.setdefault('default', 'all')
        kwargs.setdefault('help', "Activate Cache by choosing one of the list choices. e.g. -cache=local-only")
        super(CacheAction, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-cache", "--cache", action=CacheAction)
```

Comment: this is OOP in his best shapes. reminds me in one of the SOLID principles from design patterns (the gang of 4) - open for extension closed for modification. you solution extend the class in a good manner. thanks.

Comment: in class OneTimeAction, in method __call__ of the base class, the real signature of the base class is : __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None), so python will prevents you from doing so. you need to remove the **kwargs from the call to super method

Comment: @Adam If you don't pass any additional keywords, it has no effect. Accepting unknown keyword arguments and passing them on is one of the hallmarks of the correct use of `super`.

Comment: the first function __call__  you have wrote was wrong def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None,**kwargs) ! Anyway you have fixed yourself! thank you. i am stiil confused regarding *args and **kwargs and if you have a good link for a good tutoria i will be grateful if you deliver it. ( for advanced cases (like the case you have used here, not the standard tutorials like this https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/
for example, why python uses in its built in functions in the same function e.g def foo(*args, **kwargs) ?? why not to use **kwargs alone!?

Comment: If you use `**kwargs` alone, then the caller *must* pass all the arguments as keyword arguments.